# How to get some system hardware information?

Tags: c#, system-information

I am trying to write a program to gain some system info.
How can we get some system hardware information like the CPU, RAM, HDD, VGA, sound, monitor and other outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the System.Management classes. Ex: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: it is useful .but some properties like model and manufacturer doesn't work this way . why ?